# CosmosDB and CORS via Portal broken?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to develop with an active CosmosDB locally. I have tried adding both my local IP/domain, as well as a wildcard * in the CORS section of CosmosDB without success.

I have also exported the resource template and see that there is no CORS property in the manifest.

The CORS errors are below:
In Chrome: `Access to fetch at 'https://--.documents.azure.com/' from origin 'https://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
In firefox: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://--.documents.azure.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

I successfully use CORS from my local 'origin' with Functions.

Comment: it should work, what do you mean by local?

Comment: I've tried `https://localhost:8080`  `https://192.168.0.96:8080` as well as `*` Using the @azure/cosmos package gives Blocked by CORS errors.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or VPN that could be changing your outbound IP?

Comment: I am not behind proxy/VPN.  CORS works with Functions just fine.

Comment: Does the CORS error give any details you can share?

Comment: In Chrome: `Access to fetch at 'https://--.documents.azure.com/' from origin 'https://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
In firefox: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://--.documents.azure.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Comment: Any fix to this issue? Can't seem to get it to work :-/